# Handling a custom backing with Java Graphics

Tags: java, graphics, drawing

I am creating a program that edits SNES GFX files in Java, and I'm drawing the data to the screen by painting a byte array to a `BufferedImage`, then painting that to the screen. The problem is, I want to be able to edit the image. Since I don't want to repaint the whole image each time, I use `BufferedImage.createGraphics()` to paint to the screen while also updating the data `byte[]` simultaneously.

This is very easy while drawing rectangles, since I can manually recreate the pixels that need to be updated in my custom data array like so:

```
for (int i = rect.x; i < rect.x + rect.width + 1; i++) {
    for (int j = rect.y; j < rect.y + rect.height + 1; j++) {
        panel.setPixelColor(new Point(i, j), palette.getCurrentColor());
    }
}
```

However, I am at a loss as to what to do for drawing ellipses. I would love to be able to just use `Graphics.drawOval()`, but I don't know if there's anyway to loop through the modified pixels to find which values I need to update. Obviously, I could use a custom ellipse-drawing algorithm, but it would be really nice to not have to reinvent the wheel.